# Problem with implementing iAd into iPhone application

Tags: iphone

okay so i have completely followed multiple tutorials step by step including this one [iAd Tutorial](http://bees4honey.com/blog/tutorial/how-to-add-iad-banner-in-iphoneipad-app/)

and using apples official sample code.. everytime i get the errors: "_CGRectOffset" Referenced from: and _CGRectZero Referenced from: any help guys?

Answer (score 0):

CGRectZero and CGRectOffset are in the CoreGraphics framework.

Comment: That worked for running it in the simulator but when i try to run it on the device the same 2 errors pop up..

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the CoreGraphics framework to your project in the linker settings.